# how can i used Set-AIPFileLabel = Unprotect-RMSFile -OutputFolder

Tags: powershell

I used commandline

Unprotect-RMSFile -Folder $vfile -OutputFolder $output -Recurse -Logfile $logfile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

is ok

but I used

Set-AIPFileLabel -RemoveProtection -RemoveLabel -Path $vfile -OutputFolder $output -Logfile $logfile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
is NG

so , I want used Set-AIPFileLabel ,how can I  do it as OutputFolder ?

Comment: [Set-AIPFileLabel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azureinformationprotection/set-aipfilelabel?view=azureipps) doesn't seem to have parameters `OutputFolder` or `Logfile`..

Comment: thanks ,but I want use "set-aipfilelabel" not change org file , out file a new file. 
do you have some good ways?